# react img rendering issue

Tags: reactjs, image, rendering

when inspecting the elements using the developer tools in React, the image appears to be rendered and visible in the preview, but it is not displaying on the screen.

The issue is with an item component that is being mapped within a list component. There are situations where this component displays correctly on the screen, but at times, it doesn't render, and the reason for this inconsistency is not known.

1. my screen is here
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwvxs.png)
2. developer tools
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45B2i.png)

and i am storing images in S3

3. my itemsComponent code

```
interface ItemPropsType {
  imgUrl: string;
  clothesId: string;
  largeCategoryId: string;
}

const SelectedClothesItem: React.FC<ItemPropsType> = ({ imgUrl, clothesId, largeCategoryId }) => {
const [imageLoaded, setImageLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const renderIngPreload = () => {
    const img = new Image();

    img.onload = () => {
      setImageLoaded(true);
    }
    img.src = imgUrl;
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    renderIngPreload();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    {imageLoaded ? (
      <img
        src={imgUrl}
        id={clothesId}
        alt={largeCategoryId}
        className={`clothes w-[110px] h-[110px] border border-gray rounded-3xl ${
          isSelected ? 'bg-gray-300 border-pink-hot border-4' : ''
        }`}
        style={{ objectFit: 'cover', minWidth: '110px', minHeight: '110px' }}
        onClick={onClickHandler}
      />
    ) : (
      <div className="animate-pulse w-[110px] h-[110px] bg-gray-button rounded-3xl">이미지 로드가 안됏음</div>
    )}
```

i used useLayoutEffect to solve this problem but i does not work